# Can we conditionally override community template elements with custom CSS

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, guest-user

I am using **customer service** community template. I want to hide the some part of standard component for the licensed user & hide that part for guest user.

Let's consider, there is standard component named **Feed Post & Comments**. I want to show the red highlighted part for authenticated users but, not for Guest user.

I know that we can hide this by making changes in CSS of community but, it will hide for both authenticated user as well as guest users. Refer below screenshot.

Please let me know is there any way to add **condition** in CSS of community

[image]

Comment: I would think that this is something you might be able to turn off using permissions / community settings. I'd investigate that first.

Comment: Please @Caspar let me know if you got something.